# How to update local files to Google Drive using command line Linux

Tags: linux, file-upload, command-line, drive

I am new to Linux and I want to upload/update my local files to Google Drive automatically using the Linux command. Does someone have experience before? Appreciate it if someone can provide me with my resources/step by step to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic approach, just tested it so it should work.

1. Get [gdrive](https://github.com/glotlabs/gdrive.git), maybe it's already available in your distribution's repo, if not download the latest release or build it from source.
2. Now we will need to give access to Google Drive to allow this program to connect to your account. To do this, insert below command. The program will ask for a Google Client ID and Client Secret, it will also give a link to a page explaining how to get those two informations.

```bash
 gdrive account add
```

3. Now we are done... Let's upload a file.

```bash
 gdrive upload /file_path
```

For example,

```bash
 gdrive files upload /opt/subhash.txt
```

4. Go to google drive and check it's uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Tzig for the info!

Comment: ..and the article is not available any more. This is why Stack Overflow answers should be self-supporting.

Comment: @Scholar thanks for telling me, I definitely had my share of bad answers. Hopefully the edit stays online longer.

Comment: are you suggesting people download a file from an unverified google docs url, make it executable and run it with sudo permissions? Sounds risky!!

Comment: @craq it was something downloaded from Google themselves. Obviously I'm not too happy about closed source binaries but in this specific case it seemed like Google had very little incentive in breaking your computer. In any case, I've since edited my answer to use an open source alternative since the original binary apparently doesn't exist anymore.